# Why not to use Ωβλδεαθφψωϕϖ (non-ASCII chars) in Python code?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, non-ascii-characters

..I find that when coding very "math-heavy" function in python one way of making the code more readable (to me at least) is by following the literature as tightly as possible, including using the greek letters such as Ω, θ, φ, ψ, ω, ϕ etc.

And the code works as expected, but PyCharm highlights those characters and says "non-ASCII characters in identifier".

..without referencing any PEP (Python coding standard).

[image]

**I'm asking for sober arguments as to why I should refrain from using non-ASCII characters in identifiers.**

Comment: Semi-***opinion*** based comment: [Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex. Readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) ***&*** [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) ➫ I go with non-ASCIIs. Moreover, using those characters is actually a good manner to create enforced-private variables names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they're not included in a standard qwerty keyboard and would be a pain in the arse to keep referring to in your code.

You're better off just referring to them by their ascii equivalents (the string `alpha` etc.) and letting intellisense in modern ide's handle the typing.

---

If you're looking for a pep standard, you probably want [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/)

> Should identifiers be allowed to contain any Unicode letter?
>
> Drawbacks of allowing non-ASCII identifiers wholesale:
>
> - Python will lose the ability to make a reliable round trip to a
>   human-readable display on screen or on paper.
> - Python will become vulnerable to a new class of security exploits; code and submitted
>   patches will be much harder to inspect.
> - Humans will no longer be able
>   to validate Python syntax.
> - Unicode is young; its problems are not yet well understood and solved; tool support is weak.
> - Languages with non-ASCII identifiers use different character sets and normalization
>   schemes; PEP 3131's choices are non-obvious.
> - The Unicode bidi algorithm yields an extremely confusing display order for RTL text when digits or operators are nearby.

Of course this has been accepted so its pycharm's decision, not pep.

Comment: "intellisense"? maybe you know of a trick that I don't.. can I set PyCharm to convert the visual depiction???.

The argument that they are not present on the keyboard are not really that relevant if I happen to have them on my keyboard right? ;).. I mean they are in fact ordinary letters used in the greek alphabet..

Comment: If you type the letter `a` then ide's such as pycharm/vscode tend to suggest that you are typing `alpha`, most projects are worked on as a team so your own keyboard probably doesn't speak to the masses

Comment: My PyCharm doesn't suggest "alpha" when I type "a"... Your arguments are not bad arguments but I don't consider them be-all-end-all, will leave the question open for others to share their opinions as well, but thanks for the answer... edit: thanks for expanding on / adding more depth to you answer, makes it more relevant..

Comment: @Vinzent - I've extended the answer to include the relevant pep standard you're probably looking for, I've kept my own thoughts above it because I still think that has some reasoning in the rationale into the warning you're seeing